# How do I interpret this promise-related Ember error?

Tags: ember-data, promise

This error appears to occur after my application saves an Ember Data record it has just created.

[image]

Comment: Try turning on the "Pause on Caught Exceptions" option in devtools and catch it in the act.

Comment: Brilliant!  This allowed me to view the call stack, which led me to a more informative error message: "An adapter cannot assign a new id to a record that already has an id."